# Flutter gives an error "_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)" in the "app_localizations.dart" file

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, emulation, dart-null-safety

[image]

I used localization on a simple app with a NavigationBar on the bottom. When I tried to run the app, it gave me an error saying exception has occured: _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

When I tried to resume it anyway, debug console said:

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
Null check operator used on a null value

I searched it for hours, I'm both tired and sick of these errors popping off. Just when I thought the app would work, it didn't so I REALLY NEED HELP :(((
Sorry if my grammar is not correct or something idk

Here is my `pubspec.yaml`

```
name: family_app
description: A social media project made with Flutter by Sertan Hakkı İmamoğlu.

publish_to: 'none' 

    version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.17.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  add_2_calendar: ^2.1.0
  flutter_rounded_date_picker: ^2.0.2
  #firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  #cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5
  #firebase_storage: ^3.1.5
  #image_picker: ^0.6.5+3

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:

  assets:
   - assets/images/title.png
   - assets/images/bg.png
   - assets/images/waiting.png

  uses-material-design: true

  # Enable generation of localized Strings from arb files.
  generate: true
```

Comment: Provide your raw code

Comment: @Denzel I added the pub codes, the others are not needed because there are just imports of localizations and usages of them

Comment: Flutter Localizations is not available on Flutter 3.0.1 downgrade to 2.10 it would work.